# PHP & regex to extract two separate parts of a string as ONE recombined variable

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP string consisting of HTML code as follows:

```
$string =
'<ul>
<li>
<a href="/nalcrom">Nalcrom</a>
        (Sodium Cromoglicate)
</li>
<li>
<a href="/alimemazine">Alimemazine</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/xolair">Xolair</a>
        (Omalizumab)
</li>
</ul>';
```

using

```
preg_match_all($regex,$string,$matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); ++$i)
{ echo $i . "    " . $matches[0][$i]. "<br>"; }
```

if I use

```
$regex = "^(?<=>).*?(?=(\Q</a>\E))^";
```

I get

1 Nalcrom

2 Alimemazine

3 Xolair

whereas if I use

```
$regex = "^\(.*?\)^";
```

I get

1 (Sodium Cromoglicate)

2 (Omalizumab)

Trying

```
$regex = "^(?<=>).*?(?=(\Q</a>\E))(\(.*?\))^";
```

and variations upon it I get nothing but blank, whereas what I need is:

1 Nalcrom (Sodium Cromoglicate)

2 Alimemazine

3 Xolair (Omalizumab)

Any ideas on how I can do this? thnx

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for this, I'd just strip the tags then work the formatting out.

Comment: @user3306881 Still alive ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the second regex group optional `?`, i.e.:

```
   $string =
    '<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="/nalcrom">Nalcrom</a>
            (Sodium Cromoglicate)
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="/alimemazine">Alimemazine</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="/xolair">Xolair</a>
            (Omalizumab)
    </li>
    </ul>';

    preg_match_all('%">(.*?)</a>\s+(\(.*?\))?%i', $string, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($match[0]); $i++) {
        echo  $match[1][$i] . " ". $match[2][$i];
    }
```

---

Output:

```
Nalcrom (Sodium Cromoglicate)
Alimemazine 
Xolair (Omalizumab)
```

---

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/mxGthV)

Comment: Thanks - this very nearly achieved it - but it left the un-bracketed words as a hyperlink.  But this did achieve what I needed: %(?<=>)(.*?)</a>\s+(\(.*?\))?%i - so very many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non regex solution. This gets rid of all HTML then uses new lines as indicators for data points. If the new line starts with a `(` it presumes it belongs with the previous point and appends it there.

```
<?php
$string =
'<ul>
<li>
<a href="/nalcrom">Nalcrom</a>
        (Sodium Cromoglicate)
</li>
<li>
<a href="/alimemazine">Alimemazine</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/xolair">Xolair</a>
        (Omalizumab)
</li>
</ul>';
$new_string = strip_tags($string);
$newlines = explode("\n", $new_string);
$count = 0;
$output = '';
foreach($newlines as $newline) {
    $newline = trim($newline);
    if(!empty($newline)) {
        if(preg_match('~^\(~', $newline)) {
            $output .= $newline;
        } else {
            $count++;
            if(!empty($output)) {
                $output .= "\n\n";
            }
            $output .=  $count . ' ' .$newline . ' ';
        }
    }
}
echo $output;
```

Then output is:

> 1 Nalcrom (Sodium Cromoglicate)
>
> 2 Alimemazine
>
> 3 Xolair (Omalizumab)

Comment: Thanks - appreciated - though the regex way was achievable in the end (see below).

Comment: Yes, regex way is achievable there are numerous threads on why you shouldn't use regexs on HTML though most importantly because the structure can change and the regex will fail. Say for instance you add an image tag inside your anchor element. These aren't going to work... of course my solution can fail as well if you get rid of new lines, etc.

Comment: I am a novice at all this so will take on board what you are saying for future reference.  All replies very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
@>([^<]+)</a>([^<]*)</li>@ius
```

In your example $matches[1][0] and trim($matches[2][0]) should return respectively Nalcrom and Sodium Cromoglicate. So you can iterate over your list using the second index.

My example needs trim to keep the regex simple, but in practice you can twist it so that it doesnt capture blank char.

Comment: Why are you using the modifiers you've selected?

Comment: good point, it's not needed here. i is to ignore case (but no need here), s is for . to match new line (but no . in the regex) and u is to tell that it's UTF8 (useful to handle multiple bit character like in japanese).   
I systematically includes those to avoids some suprises, but it's not necessary in this case.

Comment: Yea, I know their uses, I wasn't sure if I'd missed something in the question and they were needed. I like to try to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: I wasn't assuming you didn't know, I put explanations to clarify the answer for any readers.  And great to hear you like to keep thing simple,  I personally like to keep things as complicated as possible ;)